# Android: Google API MapView - setTraffic stopped working for eastern Europe

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-mobile

I have been using MapView for a long time and everything was working properly but after some time people started complaining about my app **not displaying the traffic**.

I checked and it really stopped working. I have tried everything to get it working back but to no avail. What I noticed though was then when I zoomed out I saw **the traffic is there for the US, CA, Spain, Germany, Austria** and others but not for Poland, Slovakia, Czech Republic...

However, the thing is that the **traffic info is there in the genuine Google Maps app** and also on the Google Maps web version for Poland, Czech Republic and these countries. It is all there but in my app and probably other apps too the traffic information for these countries is missing.

Now I am sure I cannot do anything about this and I wonder how and to whom submit a bug report on this? Do you have any idea how to proceed? Thank you

Comment: Ok never mind. I ditched MapView completely and work directly with Google Maps via Intents. Not so elegant but you get all those extra features that Google Maps provide